# Mangento on localhost points to online site

Tags: mysql, magento

I have a fresh magento 1.7 using a copied sql from a shop online.  The shop is using Mag 1.4 so the idea is to update the DB to 1.7.  After linking the 1.7 shop to the DB on localhost, it is error free, however 127.0.0.1/shop redirects to the online store.

Changing base_url does not help.

The DB still has references to the online site, but I dont see any reference that would make a difference.

This seems to be a common problem with out any solutions?
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/280257/#t387542
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/224658/#t313216

UPDATE -

The question at http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/280257/#t387542
has been updated with a comprehensive answer by chiefair, like the one given by Fiasco Labs below - if you are in need of more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed your base URL settings in the Magento database and it's still going to the old base URLs. You started Magento once before changing them and it cached the old configuration and now you're locked onto the old site.

For Linux, change your var/ directory structure to chmod -R 777. You don't have write permissions there and Magento has established a cache in /tmp as it needed somewhere to write the cache files. It's cached the config settings and will not reread them until the cache is in the right directory location. If there are subdirectories in var/cache, delete them all. You might have to go hunting for /tmp/*/var/cache and delete those as well.

Edit: Same goes for Mac and Windows, if you've got the database changed and can see the changes took in phpMyAdmin, you have manually cleaned out your var/cache subdirectories,  given Apache a restart, and the system is still redirecting, you early on, had a misconfiguration that wrote Magento's cache elsewhere. That is why it's persistent. Usually a machine reboot will clear it on Mac and Linux as they do housekeeping on their temp folders when the OS restarts.

Here are screenshots of the system **/tmp** Magento cache storage in action on a Linux server with bad file permissions.

**Pay attention to the top address bar in both images...**

[image: Pay attention to the top address bar in the image...]

**And here's your hidden cache that's causing you difficulties.**

[image: And here's your hidden cache that's causing you difficulties.]

Comment: Makes sense - thanks.  if im on localhost what do you mean by  chmod -R 777  I would do that on ftp?

Comment: What OS is this test server running on?

Comment: Depending on where you installed your XAMPP services, Apache may not have write permissions in its document root folder tree. Find what user the Apache service is running under and look in the local temp folders. TEMP=C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp are where Magento's cache is probably being sent with interminable hilarity as unlike *nix, these folders are not cleared on reboot, so you could have a really persistent Magento cache.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following steps:

1. Clear your browser's cookies
2. Take a peek in the DB in table `core_config_data` at the rows `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url`
3. Manually clear the `var/session` and `var/cache` folders

For a complete tutorial, see [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/moving_magento_to_another_server).

Comment: as I mentioned the base_url doesnt help.  I even replaced all mentions of the old URL on the whole site and it didnt help.  I used a brand new browser and it didnt help.  I was using my own local.xml file, and I did an install using my DB but let mage create the local.xml and it seems to be working.  But cant work out what the problem was

Comment: You can see from the magentocommerce posts that they also changed the base_url and had no luck

Comment: Well, in this case, there are many things that can go wrong. You need to take it step by step and make sure that the issue is not caused by something hardcoded in a certain file, like htaccess. Do a grep on all the files. Are you using the compilation plugin? Are you using JS & CSS minification? Try to clear the browser cache, restart it and delete the magento cache each time you perform one of these tests.

Comment: its a clean download with no extenstions.  how do you clear mage cache in the DB, w/o access to the admin section (cause it redrects!)

Comment: I don't understand. If you changed the base_url entries in your local DB manually, then the admin should read and use the updated entries. The redirects are coming from another source, which you will have to identify.

Comment: exactly.  You can see the magento board posts also changed base_url to no effect - so what is the cause....

Answer (score 0):

Re installing from the same DB, by deleting app/etc/local.xml and pointing the new install to this DB worked.  But I can't work out why the local file was sending the site elsewhere.  Maybe in the encrypted key?

Comment: It forced a re-read of the configuration settings in the database and cached these new settings you put in the database. You still need to check permissions on var/ and make sure the web server can write to them. This only may have forced a change into the ones in /tmp and you will have problems crop up later till the permissions are correct.