# Magento DEV. clone are redirectingg to the main URL

Tags: php, magento, migration, upgrade

I'm trying to clone a Magento site , in order to upgrade and then copy it back to the production folder.

I was following this tutorial: http://www.duntuk.com/magento-upgrade

I've done everything just its told to do, but when I try to access the URL: `dev.mysite.com` its redirects to `mysite.com`.

I already changed the lines in `core_config_data` and also changed database settings the `app/etc/local.xml`

What is happening?

Comment: Duplicate of several different questions asked here and on magento.stackexchange. It's quite common for this to happen. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178264/moved-magento-site-to-another-host-redirecting-to-the-old-site/26188706#26188706 | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836400/mangento-on-localhost-points-to-online-site/10837274#10837274 | http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37302/magento-redirects-to-old-website-regardless-of-what-changes-are-made | http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31148/local-xml-points-to-local-host-but-magento-says-its-on-old-server

Comment: Here's another http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30404784/magento-database-transfer-oddity/30418659?noredirect=1#comment49003118_30418659